# Close Java InputStream after pass to Spring JDBC LobHandler?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, blob, inputstream

Does it need manually close InputStream (bean.getContentAsStream()) in java after pass to Spring JDBC lobCreator.setBlobAsBinaryStream(,,) in such code?

```
 getJdbcTemplate().execute(
                "INSERT INTO file (" +
                "id, " +                      //1
                "FILE_DATA) " +               //2
                " VALUES (?, ?)",
                 // lobhandler is instance of org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler
                new AbstractLobCreatingPreparedStatementCallback(lobhandler){
                    @Override
                    protected void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, LobCreator lobCreator) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                        ps.setString(1, bean.getRecordId());
                        lobCreator.setBlobAsBinaryStream(ps, 2, bean.getContentAsStream(), (int) bean.getContentSize());
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect spring will close it but the doc does not say. You can easily test by creating an InputStream wrapper that logs a message or throws an exception when it is closed.